# Data Migration options from Exadata to non-exadata system

Tags: oracle, datapump, rman, exadata

Has anyone tried using rman or an export to move data from an oracle exadata instance to a non-exadata instance?

Comment: try Cloud Services such as GCP: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration/oracle-migration

Comment: If you're moving data from one instance to another, Datapump would be the preferred solution. It doesn't matter if either the source or destination instance runs on Exadata.